# textRecognizer.isOperational() return false

Tags: java, android, image, google-play-services, vision

i run the app in emulator it works but run it in phone api 17 and api 22 textRecognizer.isOperational() return false

what is the problem?

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES" android:value="ocr"/>
</application>
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

SurfaceView CameraView;
TextView textView;
CameraSource cameraSource;
final int RequestCameraPermissionID = 1001;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    CameraView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);

    final TextRecognizer textRecognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(this).build();

    if (!textRecognizer.isOperational()) {
        Log.w("MainActivity", "dependencies are not available");
    } else {
        cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(getApplicationContext(), textRecognizer)
                .setFacing(CameraSource.CAMERA_FACING_BACK)
                .setRequestedPreviewSize(1280, 1024)
                .setRequestedFps(2.0f)
                .setAutoFocusEnabled(true)
                .build();

        CameraView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},RequestCameraPermissionID);
                    return;
                }
                try {
                    cameraSource.start(CameraView.getHolder());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                cameraSource.stop();
            }
        });
        textRecognizer.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<TextBlock>() {
            @Override
            public void release() {

            }

            @Override
            public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<TextBlock> detections) {
                final SparseArray<TextBlock> item = detections.getDetectedItems();
                if(item.size() != 0){
                    textView.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                            for (int i=0;i<item.size();i++){
                                TextBlock items = item.valueAt(i);
                                stringBuilder.append(items.getValue());
                                stringBuilder.append("\n");
                            }
                            textView.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode){
        case RequestCameraPermissionID:
            if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return;
                }
                try {
                    cameraSource.start(CameraView.getHolder());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    }
}
```

}

please help thanks
emulator api 25
phone huawei g730 u10 api 17
Imet api 22

Everytime I launch the apk, "Text recognizer could not be set up : is displayed. Even though I have set all dependencies but still i am getting this error. Please help why TextRecognizer.isOperational() is always false.